# SQL Server keeps trying to insert data into my IDENTITY Column

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2017 to build a database project and whenever I seem to run this query I get the same error message back.

> "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12 Franks Place' to data type int.".

I don't understand why I'm getting this message because to my understanding it neither of these commands should work access the primary key column. Some insight into what I'm doing wrong would be much-appreciated.

This is the table I'm trying to insert data into:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Address]
    (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    [StreetAddress] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    [Suburb] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    [PostCode] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    [Country] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    [State] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [AK_Address_NoPK] UNIQUE (StreetAddress, Suburb, PostCode, Country)
    )
```

These are the commands I'm trying to execute:

```
INSERT INTO Address (StreetAddress, Suburb, PostCode, Country, State)
Values ('12 Franks Place', 'scary sea', '4321', 'Australia', 'S.A');

INSERT INTO Address
Values ('12 Franks Place', 'scary sea', '4321', 'Australia', 'S.A');
```

and they both return me this error message:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12 Franks Place' to data type int.

Sorry if I have laid this post out poorly or my question is too vague this is my first time posting on this site.

Comment: I would not expect this error.  Are you sure that this is the actual code which generated that error?  Is it possible that your query/table has become stale?

Comment: The same is not repeating for me. You might missed some script..

Comment: Are you sure they both fail?  try commenting out the second statement since it doesn't say the name of the columns.

Comment: if this is really your script then you should check hidden trigger.

Comment: `INSERT INTO Address
Values ('12 Franks Place', 'scary sea', '4321', 'Australia', 'S.A');` is bound to give you error of Identity insert. The first insert is correct. Do a `SELECT` on Address table and you should see 1 entry.

Comment: i ran your code in sql server it deosn' t raise any error unless you insert duplicate records because you created unique key constraint CONSTRAINT [AK_Address_NoPK] UNIQUE (StreetAddress, Suburb, PostCode, Country)